# lambdametafactory creation is quite slow compared to just using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, reflection, methodhandle, lambda-metafactory

```
@Benchmark
public void testLambdaGeneration(Blackhole bh) {
    Function<Object, Object> function = a -> {
        if(a instanceof Alpha alpha) {
            return alpha.primitiveInt();
        }else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    };
    bh.consume(function);
}

@Benchmark
public void testManualGeneration(Blackhole bh) {
    try{
        MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(Alpha.class, "primitiveInt", MethodType.methodType(int.class));
        MethodType type = mh.type();
        type = type.changeReturnType(Integer.class);
        CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(MethodHandles.lookup(),
                "apply",
                MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
                type.erase(), mh, type);
        Function<Object, Object> f = (Function<Object, Object>) callSite.getTarget().invokeExact();
        bh.consume(f);
    }catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unreached");
    }
}
```

I want to use lambdametafactory to create constructor, getter and setter methods for reflection usage, and generated Function<> is just as fast as the direct call, which greatly satisfies my needs. However, when I use the above code to test the generation performance between lambdafactory and pure lambda, the result is quite unpromising:

```
LambdaTest.testLambdaGeneration  avgt   50      0.574 ±     0.015  ns/op
LambdaTest.testManualGeneration  avgt   50  29424.815 ± 20402.801  ns/op
```

I think the lambda function would use LambdaMetafactory internally, so the result should be consistent, but the actual result really shock me.

Is there any thing wrong with my code? How could I improve the LambdaMetafactory.metafactory()'s performance to match the pure lambda generation?

Comment: When using a lambda directly the LambdaMetafactory is only used once - that result is cached by the `invokedynamic` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version I wrote.

```
private Function<Object, Object> cachedFunction;

@Setup
public void setup() {
    try {
        MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(Alpha.class, "primitiveInt", MethodType.methodType(int.class));
        MethodType type = mh.type().changeReturnType(Integer.class);
        CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(MethodHandles.lookup(),
                "apply",
                MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
                type.erase(), mh, type);
        cachedFunction = (Function<Object, Object>) callSite.getTarget().invokeExact();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Setup failed", e);
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void testCachedManualGeneration(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(cachedFunction.apply(new Alpha()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand this way having the same performance as using direct call, what I want to emphasize is the lambda generation performance difference. (The performance of creating the Function<>)

Comment: @benrush Your lambda is non-capturing, so the instance is only created once and then cached. The code in this answer more or less equivalent to what the runtime does, except that the field would be `static final`.

Comment: @JornVernee I understand that if it's defined as static final, or the runtime initialized it as  static final, both the generation performance and invoking performance should be the same as direct call, however this requires the information known as we were coding, when developing something like a json library, it requires accessing methods at runtime, and both the generation performance and invoking performance matters. Is there any solution that the generation process in my code example could be speed up?

Comment: @benrush No, it can not be sped up. The way to make your code faster is to either not use LMF, i.e. just use a lambda expression if possible, if the type of the functional interface you want is known in advance. Note that it's also possible to wrap the MethodHandle call inside a lambda expression. Use the MethodHandles directly. Or cache the CallSite instance that LMF creates, so that it doesn't have to be re-created every time (which is very expensive). You might also want to try out MethodHandleProxies.

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks for your answer, I will try using the other mechanisms that you mention. I think the ultimate weapon for runtime generation problem might be the preview class-file API in JEP 457, the classfile generation performance should be better than the my example above, but further tests are needed.

Comment: @benrush it seems you are expecting magic from JEP 457. [It’s even stated explicitly](https://openjdk.org/jeps/457): “*It is not a goal to obsolete existing libraries that process class files, nor to be the world's fastest class-file library.*” And it doesn’t change the fundamental problem that code generation only pays off when you generate once (or a few times) and use the generated code often. That doesn’t mean that you can’t use code generation in a dynamic context. But you still [need a cache](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassValue.html)